# Program does not output numbers less than 5

Tags: java, output, palindrome

I have a question to input a 5 digit integer.
The program will output if it is a palindrome or not.
And it will display "not a palindrome" if integer is not a palindrome.

But the problem is that the program crash whenever i input a less than 5 digit integer.
Else everything is fine. The program even output "not a 5 digit number" when i input an integer with more than 5 digit.

Here is my code.

```
String input1;
int number, number2, a, b, d, e;

input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 5 digit number");

a = input1.charAt(0);
b = input1.charAt(1);
d = input1.charAt(3);
e = input1.charAt(4);

number2 = input1.length();
number = Integer.parseInt(input1);

if (number2 >= 6) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a 5 digit number");
}
if (number2 <= 4) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a 5 digit number");
}

if ((a == e) && (b == d)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Palindrome");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a palindrome");
}
```

Comment: what do you think happens when `input1` is less than 5 and you do `e = input1.charAt(4);`

Comment: Forget about `a, b, c, d, e`. Use `if (input1.charAt(0) == input1.charAt(number-1-0)` with a counter/index you can then have a general solution for all lengths.

Answer (score 0):

`number2 <= 4` will not Filter out 4 digit numbers.
Also, proof the lenght before you `e = input1.charAt(4);`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to re-arrange your code. `input1.charAt(4)` could fail if `input1.length() < 5`

```
input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 5 digit number");   

number2 = input1.length();
number = Integer.parseInt(input1);

if (number2 >= 6) { 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a 5 digit number"); 
    return;
}
if (number2 <= 4) { 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a 5 digit number"); 
    return;
}

a = input1.charAt(0);
b = input1.charAt(1);
d = input1.charAt(3);
e = input1.charAt(4);

if ((a == e) && (b == d)) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Palindrome"); }
else { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a palindrome"); }
```

Comment: you could shorten the ifs to `if(number>=6 || number<=4)`

Answer (score 0):

So the reason your program crashes is because you are getting the char at position x which may or may not exist. So if your length of the input is smaller than x , your code will throw an exception.

You can solve this by Adding a check before `a = input1.charAt(0);` like

```
 if (input1.length() <5){  
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a 5 digit number");  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> But the problem is that the program crash whenever i input a less than
>   5 digit integer.

It crashes because you can not access array element with `index > array.length - 1` , for example if your array length is less than `5` i.e `4` then, your `index` should go from `index=0 to index=3` however in your case , when you input a `4` length number your index should range from `0`  to `3` . But the following will fail, because you are trying to access with `index = 4` which is out of the range index of the array.

```
e = input1.charAt(4); //
```

Edit, instead you can simplify it as the following

```
String input1;
int number2,;

input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 5 digit number");
number2 = input1.length();
if(number2 == 5) {
    if(input1.substring(0,2).equals(input1.substring(4,5)+input1.substring(3,4)))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Palindrome");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a palindrome");
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a 5 digit number");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was stated by many people but I will try to improve your code block in general.

Your issue is the block:

```
a = input1.charAt(0);
b = input1.charAt(1);
d = input1.charAt(3);
e = input1.charAt(4);
```

Lets say your input is "1234" the following array will exist

array["1","2","3","4]
Arrays in java and most languages begin at 0. So your available positions are 0, 1, 2 and 3. When input1.charAt(4); runs it fails.

---

**Extra Sugestions**

---

But lets try to make all of your code slightly better.

First, assuming this is all of your code the line

```
number = Integer.parseInt(input1);
```

is useless as your never need this value, let's throw it out. If you keep it you will need a try...catch block in case input1 is not a number, "abcde" will crash your application here.

Next the block where you check for the length can be simplifed and should come before you try to read anything.

```
if (number2 >= 6) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a 5 digit number");
}
if (number2 <= 4) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a 5 digit number");
}
```

can just be made into a single if with the || (Or) statement or even better then != (NOT) statement, instead of checking if its less than four or more than 6, check if its Not 5.

```
if (number2 != 5) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a 5 digit number");
}
```

And you have some better code that shouldn't fail!

```
String input1;
int number2, a, b, d, e;

input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 5 digit number");
number2 = input1.length();

if (number2 != 5) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a 5 digit number");
    return; //Dont do anything else, or you will get errors.
}

//There are better ways to do this, but this should work.
a = input1.charAt(0);
b = input1.charAt(1);
d = input1.charAt(3);
e = input1.charAt(4);

if ((a == e) && (b == d)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Palindrome");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not a palindrome");
}
```

Sorry for the verbosity but I hope it helped.